# Python background script dosn't work properly after sometime in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, python, background

I wrote a python script to tail auth log and anylse the new lines. After that It writes output to another file according to the auth.log log line.

I set that script to run in background after every reboot. It works properly for few time. After some time it dosen't write anything to that file. But it works in background.

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothesis: `auth.log` gets renamed or deleted, it stops growing. A new `auth.log` appears and starts growing. Your script sticks to the old file.

Usually this happens because of [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) or similar mechanism.

Compare [what `-f` and `-F` options of GNU `tail` do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291935/108618). My guess is your script works somewhat like `tail -f` while you expect it to work like `tail -F`.

Even if you manage to implement the other behavior, it may not be fully reliable because of fundamental issues elaborated here: [*Don't use `logrotate` or `newsyslog` in this century*](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html).